# in my language oracle report 11g output reversed text and some characters being separated

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pdf-generation, oraclereports

I use Oracle Form and report 11g r2, oracle doesn't support my language(persian/farsi) it's look like Arabic but "FARSI" have 4 characters (گ چ پ ژ) that they are not in Arabic . 
I set `NLS_CHARACTERSET = AR8MSWIN1256 and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = UTF-8` then I set my win language to Arabic so I don't have problem in PL/SQL and ORACLE FORM BUILDER 11G Run time. 
I make a Report with Oracle report builder and run it throw on of my forms. I run in in two way

1. format('HTMLCSS') and type('CAcHE')
2. format('PDF') and type('FILE') and save on Client space.

Reading-order of TEXT-ITEM-FILED is right to left (Farsi and Arabic are start from right ) because of that  In PL/SQL and in form builder in run time Order of characters are Okay but when I run report in 'HTMLCSS' order of some Characters like ('.' , ':' , ... ) being reversed and in 'PDF' output are like 'HTMLCSS' and (گ چ پ ژ) are separated like this

- "in data base -->(پنجره گالوانیزه)
- in pdf ---> (پ نجره گ الوانیره)"

and if mix Farsi and English IN PDF Output Farsi Characters reversed like this

- in data base show (نمی کند support اوراکل فارسی را)
- in pdf shows (اوراکل فارسی را support  نمی کند)

Please help me how to fix them.
TnQ.

Comment: How did you change the Character set? Usually it is quite an effort to change this: [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm)

Comment: from Registry Editor --> NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256